# How to use policy-based authorization with parameters in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I've been looking at the asp.net core [documentation for policy-base authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html) and it's not apparent how I could pass parameters to  authorization handlers.

For example, let's say that I only want to let a user access to a controller that displays a club if they are member. The user could be a member of several clubs, but not this one. Thus, I need some way to tell the authentication handler which club it needs to valid against.

Is there any way to pass an id or something to the handler in this kind of situation?

Comment: The club the handler needs to validate against is probably te part of the uri, `your.app/clubs/{name}`. If you differentiate between clubs in yet another way, make sure to edit your post and include the description so that a response could refer to it.

Comment: You are correct that that's exactly how I want to do it but how would I get the parameter `{name}` to the handler?

Comment: Inside a handler you are free to read the request's uri.

Comment: Is that the `AuthorizationContext` parameter?

Comment: Yes, the auth context has the http context inside and you have access to pretty much every detail of a request.

Comment: I see. Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: Is this not available in .net core?